# Hilt Injection not working with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

Dependency injection inside `BroadcastReceiver` using Hilt isn't working. I try to invoke a `BroadcastReceiver` using an alarm from `MainActivity` and i am getting `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`. According to the documentation it should be as simple as adding the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation to the receiver but its not.

***Sample Code:***

**App.kt:**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(App::class.simpleName, "onCreate: Application")
    }
}
```

**TestHiltInjection.kt:**

```
class TestHiltInjection @Inject constructor() {

    operator fun invoke() {
        Log.d(TestHiltInjection::class.java.simpleName, "invoke called.")
    }
}
```

**HiltBroadcastReceiver.kt:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject lateinit var testHiltInjection: TestHiltInjection

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        testHiltInjection()
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val manager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val pending = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(this, HiltBroadcastReceiver::class.java), 0)
        manager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            15000, 15000,
            pending
        )
    }
}
```

Output Logcat:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property testHiltInjection has not been initialized
```

**Update**

Issue was already solved on 2.29.1 version, just use `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Update:** According to the [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918) the problem should be fixed in version [2.29.1](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.29.1) of Dagger Hilt. So, just use version `2.29.1-alpha` or above. Don't forget to update `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` version [as well](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918#issuecomment-693095307).

---

**Original answer:** There's a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918) and a [workaround](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918#issuecomment-644057247). It seems that injection doesn't work because it actually happens inside `onReceive()` method of the generated parent class. The problem is that you cannot call the super method since it's abstract. But you can create a simple wrapper class that fixes the problem:

```kotlin
abstract class HiltBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
  @CallSuper
  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {}
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyBroadcastReceiver : HiltBroadcastReceiver() {
  @Inject lateinit var testHiltInjection: TestHiltInjection

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent) // <-- it's the trick

    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice find!! I cannot believe this wasn't catch by Google before releasing it...

Comment: A related subject @ValeriyKatkov... you have enough reputation in `dagger-hilt` tag to upvote synonyms. Could you do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dagger-hilt/synonyms ? No moderator seem to care about bringing order to `hilt` related tags, so I'm trying to coordinate that myself.

Comment: @Valeriy Katkov I used the offered workaround, thank you very much, but still the BroadcastReceiver won't invoke in my app. Is there anything else, that needs to be done? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65476494/12083845) is what I have done so far.

Comment: @Valeriy Katkov I am also facing the same issue. I tried workaround suggested by you as well as upgraded the hilt gradle plugin version, still no luck. Could you please help?

Comment: That small bit in the answer `because it actually happens inside onReceive() method of the generated parent class` was all I needed to figure out the problem. Good catch. Does anyone know why did they not make it so it injects in the generated constructor?!

Comment: The bug is fixed for Broadcast Receivers, but its still not fixed on AppWidgetProvider. Those having problem with onReceive on AppWidgetProvider should use the workaround.

Answer (score 7):

I think hilt currently doesn't support BroadcastReceiver. In https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point says

> Note: Hilt currently only supports activities that extend ComponentActivity and fragments that extend androidx library Fragment, not the (now deprecated) Fragment in the Android platform.

How it works internally: Hilt creates abstract class for `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotated component(Activity, Fragment, BroadcastReceiver etc) and your BroadcastReceiver extends generated class as base class in bytecode transformation. In base class `onReceive` method object is injected. But in generated bytecode class super class `onReceive` method is not called. That's why your object is not injected.
To test add below code before `testHiltInjection()` in `HiltBroadcastReceiver` class. By the way it's still in Alpha mode.

```
((HiltBroadcastReceiver_GeneratedInjector) BroadcastReceiverComponentManager.generatedComponent(context)).injectHiltBroadcastReceiver(UnsafeCasts.<HiltBroadcastReceiver>unsafeCast(this));
```

**Update:** Now issue has been fixed in version `2.29.1-alpha`. Also do not forget to upgrade `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` version to `2.29.1-alpha` or latest. More info on [releases](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases) .

> Fix #1918: Support BroadcastReceiver with @AndroidEntryPoint transform. (ede018b)

Comment: it works great. Yes i know its in alpha mode but the idea is to test and reports bugs. Also in the docs they dont explicity shows that BroadcastReceiver arent supported.

Comment: Nice workaround. It seems like a Hilt bug, the docs do say BroadcastReceiver is supported.

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-interfaces

Comment: I opened an issue for this on their github


https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918

Comment: @FrankHarper There is a nice workaround on your github issue here : https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1918#issuecomment-644057247

Answer (score 7):

With the stable version of Hilt. you can easily inject any variable like this

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Inject
    public DataManager dataManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Currently, you can't use `@AndroidEntryPoint` for BroadcastReceiver due to Hilt bug.
instead you use workaround logic like this

if you want to inject SomeModule in BroadcastReceiver

1. create new EntryPoint

   ```
   @EntryPoint
   @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
   interface MyEntryPoint {
       fun getSomeModule: SomeModule
   }
   ```
2. get entrypoint and use it

   ```
   class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
      override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
       val someModule : SomeModule =
         EntryPoints.get(context?.applicationContext, MyEntryPoint::class.java)
      .getSomeModule()
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Hilt is now stable. its now as simple as:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

@Inject
lateinit var getMyUseCase: MyUseCase
```